# calling java code from PHP

Tags: java, php, symfony1

I have a PHP web application developed using symfony framework. I want to call some Java code from within my PHP pages. Java code is distributed to multiple jar files and there is one interface available to access the functionality. The input and outputs of the Java interface are XML files, text files, Java beans and some more complex objects.

Is there any bridge available in PHP to call complex Java methods or some other solution to this problem. Alternatively, I have to write soap web services to solve this problem.

Comment: http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/

Comment: If you choose to implement webservices could use JSON instead of SOAP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to look at these:

- **[Zend Platform Java Bridge](http://www.zend.com/en/products/platform/product-comparison/java-bridge)**
- **[PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/)**

HTH

Answer (score 7):

you could run the java code by exec or shell_exec
ex.

```
shell_exec("java whatever.jar $parameter1 $parameter2");
```

Webservices would be the nicer solution though. IMO

Comment: how can i call a method from a jar file, and also different methods have multiple parameters. Is it possible with shell_exec? I dont thinks its possible with shell_exec

Comment: +& for webservices. That wuold be the clean way to do this.