# How to execute Java-based OWL reasoner on an Apache (not Tomcat) server?

Tags: java, php, apache, owl

I have a PHP web application that should perform reasoning on an OWL (Ontology Web Language) document. I know of two reasoners, both of which are written in Java, but I have a standard Apache server at my disposal, so I can type in PHP, not in JSP.

Is there a way to execute Java code on server, like this: the PHP script sends data to the Java code (reasoner), then Java code performs the reasoning and returns data to the PHP script? Is there a way for one Java program to be perhaps somehow wrapped in something on the server, or whatever?

Thanx,
Martin

Answer (score 2):

I think a good approach in your case would be to expose the reasoner via a SPARQL endpoint, and write your application in PHP against the SPARQL protocol.

Calling out to Java from PHP sounds like a hack, and seems brittle.  If you base your application on the SPARQL protocol, you can get away with just HTTP, JSON, & XML libs, you don't need anything strictly RDF or OWL specific.  Could simplify your implementation quite a bit.

Further, if you use SPARQL protocol, it isolates you from implementation specific details for whatever reasoner/database you're using.  You can switch to a new reasoner and as long as it's exposed as a SPARQL endpoint, you don't need to change the code in your webapp.

None of that really gets around you having to run the reasoner on a machine, and most likely you'll need a servlet container, though some options can run stand-alone.

Comment: Thanx. That sounds like a good strategy... and then I can probably connect my web app to a reasoner hosted on a physically different server - a host that provides Java web stuff. And also then I'm reasoner-transparent.

Answer (score 1):

You need first to be able to run some Java code on your machine and you have to install a JVM on your server.

Then you could look at the following answer: [calling java code from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565838/calling-java-code-from-php) . This should give you an idea how to call a Java program from PHP.

An alternative hack if you don't rely too heavily on the reasoning would be to open the ontology with Protege, classify it and then save it as such. Therefore you won't have to use any Java on the server side and you would just consume the data present in the ontology.

Comment: Thanx for the answer! JRE on the server means a lot of negotiation with the tech support but that part might be possible - and I'll look up the solutions from the answer you suggested.

And what do I need? I have users interacting with semantics. A user can add a new relation between two entities (I'm speaking very general but you'll get the idea). Then, as users add new OWL statements, some implicit data will emerge in there... so I need to invoke the reasoner after every user's interaction (or better said contribution to the semantics). Like a wiki ontology in an e-learning context.